# 5 GH/s Bitcoin Miner from Butterfly Labs can mine Litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, asic, mining-hardware, scrypt

I was wondering buy this [ASIC miner](https://products.butterflylabs.com/homepage/5-gh-s-bitcoin-miner.html) of 5GH/s to mine Litecoin. 
[image]

I want know, can I mine Litecoin with this powerful tool? If not, there any ASIC miner's that can mine Litecoin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Litecoin uses a different proof of work than Bitcoin, so that hardware won't be compatible(it won't be solving the right problems).

One of the motivations of Litecoin was to make CPU mining viable by making it difficult to create efficient GPU/FPGA/ASIC miners, so it's unlikely that you can find specialized hardware for this purpose. I think that some GPUs do give a speedup over CPU mining with Litecoin, but it isn't as dramatic as with Bitcoin.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't mine Litecoin with any of Butterfly Labs' products. There is an ASIC miner in development by Alpha Tech http://alpha-t.net/ that they claim will be able to.

Comment: Will these Alpha Tech miners which mine scrypt based coins like Litecoin, be able to mine scrypt-jane based coins like Yacoin?

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, UK-Based [Alpha Technologies](http://alpha-t.net) are about to release a Litecoin/Scrypt-capable ASIC ship miner, which should speed up mining Scrypt-based coins substantially.

http://alpha-t.net/product/scrypt-asic-miner

Comment: +1 He was proposing an alternative that may be able to do what OP wanted to do with the Butterfly Labs miner.

Comment: @AustinBurk, thanks for the support mate, yes was only  being helpful.

Comment: @Murch u trollin..

Comment: Just be careful about these sorts of things. Lots of scammers pop up claiming to build ASICs with inflated claims of their efficiency (or existence).