# Butterfly Jalapeño for Dogecoin?

Tags: mining-hardware, dogecoin, scrypt, butterfly-labs

Can a Butterfly Jalapeño be used to mine dogecoin? If so, is it cost effective, compared to it's bitcoin mining cost effectiveness?

Comment: related: [5 GH/s Bitcoin Miner from Butterfly Labs can mine Litecoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/17500/5406)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the [Jalapeño](https://products.butterflylabs.com/4-5gh-bitcoin-miner.html) is a Bitcoin miner, it solves the **SHA-256d** hash function.

On the other hand, Dogecoin uses the **Scrypt** hash function. The two are not compatible, and as far as I know there is no Scrypt ASIC being sold, yet.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, it isn't possible because Dogecoin uses Scrypt. However, you could try GPU mining. Their are FPGA implementations and "rumors" of a company attempting to create a Scrypt ASIC ( although due to its memory usage it would prove somewhat difficult ).